# How to adjust the plot area to make it equal with other figure when you have a upscribe in the axis title?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I encounter a question which bothered me a lot!
Like this, the upscribe in the axis title seems changed the plot area.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVbJb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the space between axis and axis.title ...

```
d <- dplyr::tibble(X=1:10,
                Y=10:1)

p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(d,ggplot2::aes(x=X,y=Y)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point() + 
  ggplot2::xlab("test") +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.title.x=ggplot2::element_text(margin=ggplot2::margin(t=10)))

p2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(d,ggplot2::aes(x=X,y=Y)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point() + 
  ggplot2::xlab("test²") +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.title.x=ggplot2::element_text(margin=ggplot2::margin(t=10)))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1,p2,nrow=1)
```

Comment: HI thanks！ But p1 and p2 are exactly the same in your code except the xlab?

Comment: I thought that was the problem you had? Maybe you could provide a minimal working example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new here. But even with your code, I still got two different-size plot area. one difference is test² dosen't work in my Rstudio, I don't why. So I changed it as "expression(test^2)". Is that the problem？ Thank a lot for your reply!

Comment: Hm. Seems like test² is limited to text height whereas expression(test^2) needs more than one row? ... I think it might be a hacky solution, but you could still go for margin. You just need to adjust them individually. 10 and 5 worked for me (but I guess it depends on font size etc)

Comment: Thank you so much! the margin setting really works!